# Integrals and signed areas

Tags: calculus

The average of the function $\sin(x)$ is zero over an interval $[0, 2\pi]$. The average of this function can be expressed in terms of two integrals, $$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x) dx + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \sin(x) dx$$  While the former is positive, the latter is negative. Having equal magnitudes, the sum gives us a zero. I wondered why the latter was negative( area is always positive! ). Then I might have realized the reason behind the negative sign. The latter lies below the $x$ axis, and to signify that, we have the negative sign.

Recently, I came across the definition of the natural logarithm.

[image]

Let us take a look at what happens in $0<x<1$. The area under the graph is above the $x$ axis while the area, defined by the definite integral, is negative( the natural logarithm takes negative values in the interval ). I am now led to believe that my reasoning behind the signs of areas is wrong. How do I overcome this problem?

---

I shall extend the text's approach here. For $x>1$, I draw a rectangle of height $\frac{1}{x}$ and width $x-1$. We see that $\ln x > \frac{1}{x} (x-1)$. Here, $ \frac{1}{x}(x-1)$ is always positive, and since $x\neq 1$, $\ln x$ is positive.

Now for $0<x<1$, $\ln x < \frac{1}{x} (x-1)$. Here, $\frac{1}{x} (x-1)$ is less than zero. Since $x\neq 1$, $\ln x$ is negative. Mathematically, this makes absolute sense( if I have not gone wrong anywhere ). But geometrically, the concept of negative sign for areas below the $x$ axis is lost to me.

Comment: Your confusion about the natural log example in the range $0<x<1$ is (if I understand you correctly) resolved as follows.  For an $x$ in that range, indeed, the integral of $1/t$ from $x$ to 1 is a positive number.  Like you say, the graph is above the axis over the whole range.  However, in the top line of that figure you provide, notice there's a minus sign that came from switching the limits of the integral.  So you're right, the area is indeed positive here but the *value* of the natural logarithm is negative due to this extra minus.

Comment: More generally, beware that integral do not compute geometrical areas but *signed* areas, depending on whether the function is positive or negative in that region.  So if the honest, positive, geometrical area is what you want, you either have to know the function is completely positive in the region of interest, or if it changed sign, you have to manually account for this.  By chopping up the region, doing a handful of integrals, flipping some signs, and adding the results up.

Comment: I get this. For that interval, $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} dt$ is computed by going from right to left. By definition, a negative sign will come in if we compute the integral from left to right. The integral is positive as suggested by the graph. It's only by definition that we get a negative. Perfect. I overlooked a simple fact here.